# Configure tmux to use zsh

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, tmux, iterm

Right now I have my iTerm session configured to use zsh (`/usr/local/bin/zsh`), but I'm trying to configure tmux to use zsh as well, instead of `/bin/bash/`, which it's currently defaulting to. So far nothing I've read up on has gotten me where I need. Any ideas or things I may have missed?

Below are some details about my current setup. Thanks!

**Check state:**

1) Open iTerm

`echo $SHELL`

> /bin/bash

`ps -p $$`

> PID TTY           TIME CMD
>   19626 ttys000    0:00.52 /usr/local/bin/zsh

2) Run tmux

`tmux`

`echo $SHELL`

> /usr/local/bin/zsh

**Configuration:**

iTerm Profiles > General > Command:

> /usr/local/bin/zsh

In .tmux.conf:

> set-option -g default-shell /usr/local/bin/zsh

Comment: According to 2) tmux *is* using Zsh as your shell. What is your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that executing `ps -p $$` in tmux prints: `20201 ttys001    0:00.02 -bash`. Even though the $SHELL variable seems to be set, tmux doesn't actually seem to be using zsh. Also, on this machine powerline's only been configured for bash. Every time I start tmux, powerline's definitely visible.

Answer (score 27):

You need to set `default-command`:

```
set -g default-command /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

`default-shell` variable only use to create a login shell, when `default-command` is empty - which is default value.

Or you can simply change your default shell to `zsh`, in this case, `tmux` will start a login shell, instead of non-login shell.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: @JustianMeyer: Can you show me your `.tmux.conf`?

Comment: @JustianMeyer Did you restart tmux with `killall tmux; tmux` command?

Comment: One minor point, in this way, it start zsh as non-login shell, not login shell.

Answer (score 4):

On top of what @cuonglm said, check for references to bash in your `.tmux.conf`.

For example, I was using a typical integration for copying & pasting in iTerm on Mac:

`set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"`

... which, to function properly with zsh had to be changed to:

`set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to isolate this tmux setup from your regular, default one. One elegant solution is to use the combination of `$SHELL` and `-L`:

Set up an alias like so:

```bash
alias zshtmux='SHELL=/usr/local/bin/zsh tmux -L zsh'
```

This creates a seperate tmux instance named `zsh`. This instance will have default shell tempororily changed to `/usr/local/bin/zsh`, sepereate from the other tmux instances.

From here, you can work with this instance using `zshtmux`:

```
zshtmux new
zshtmux attach
```